# How do I determine the domain of the inverse function if the domain of the original is given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If we have that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         4x - 11 & \text{if $x < 3$}\\
         -\dfrac{4}{3}x + 9 & \text{if $3 \leq x \leq 6$}\\[2 mm]
         2x - 7 & \text{if $x > 6$}
\end{cases}
$$

I know how to determine each inverse of $f(x)$, but how do I determine its domain? For example, $f(x) = 4x - 11$, the inverse is $(x+11)/4$, but what do I put instead of if $x < 3$? Is it if $x < 1$ in this case? so the range of the original function?

Comment: Yes, it's the range of the original. Or, like you suggest, rearrange until you can write down the inverse, and look for issues: are there square roots that may take negative arguments? Could the denominator evaluate to zero?

Comment: My suggestion is to draw the graph of the total function as accurately as you can. Then the answer should jump out at you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.